# DAX get N'th last non-blank value

Tags: powerbi, dax

For any given date, I would like to get an average Sales of the most recent 3 days with non-blank sales. So I need to retrieve not only the last non-blank sales (which might be easy) but I also need to get the second last and third last sales. Generally, I need N'th last sales.

Sample data:

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+
|    Date    | Amount | N'th 1 | N'th 2 | N'th 3 | Expected Results |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 2021-02-01 |      1 |      1 |        |        |             1.00 |
| 2021-02-02 |      2 |      2 |      1 |        |             1.50 |
| 2021-02-03 |      2 |      2 |      2 |      1 |             1.67 |
| 2021-02-04 |        |      2 |      2 |      1 |             1.67 |
| 2021-02-05 |      3 |      3 |      2 |      2 |             2.33 |
| 2021-02-06 |        |      3 |      2 |      2 |             2.33 |
| 2021-02-07 |        |      3 |      2 |      2 |             2.33 |
| 2021-02-08 |      4 |      4 |      3 |      2 |             3.00 |
| 2021-02-09 |        |      4 |      3 |      2 |             3.00 |
| 2021-02-10 |        |      4 |      3 |      2 |             3.00 |
| 2021-02-11 |        |      4 |      3 |      2 |             3.00 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

The N'th 1 is the last "non-blank" sales. The N'th 2 is the "last but one". The expected result is the average of N1, N2, N3.

Link to sample data file with solutions suggested by accepted answer:
[DAX Rolling Average NonBlanks.pbix](https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1CtfbKeTk3aVb_3XxjUU-coWOJ_RWSil3&export=download)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my take (it's a measure):

```
Non-blank average = 
var curDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Date], MAX(Data[Date]))
var nonBlankTab = FILTER(ALL(Data), NOT(ISBLANK(Data[Amount])) && Data[Date] <= curDate)
var rankedTab = FILTER ( ADDCOLUMNS ( nonBlankTab, "Rank", RANKX ( nonBlankTab, [Date] ) ), [Rank] <= 3 )
return AVERAGEX(rankedTab, [Amount])
```

**EDIT**:

Just an explanation:

- the measure is calculated for the selected date. If no date context is present, the latest date is assumed.
- Then I filter out the table to contain only rows with non blank sales not later than curDate
- Then I rank the dates so that the latest 3 dates always receive ranks 1, 2 and 3.
- Then I filter out all the dates with rank higher than 3
- Finally, I calculate an average over the remaining 3 data points.

[image]

**EDIT2:**

I simplified the measure a bit - lastSalesDate is not necessary. Also, as per request in the comments, I left the first attempt as it was, and here is the modified version with TOPN instead of ADDCOLUMNS/RANKX/FILTER combo:

```
Non-blank average = 
var curDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Date], MAX(Data[Date]))
var nonBlankTab = FILTER(ALL(Data), NOT(ISBLANK(Data[Amount])) && Data[Date] <= curDate)
var rankedTab = TOPN(3, nonBlankTab, [Date])
return AVERAGEX(rankedTab, [Amount])
```

**EDIT3:**

A more universal version of the measure that just removes filters from `Date` column, which is actually all we need. No need to butcher all the other filters on the table:

```
Non-blank average = 
var curDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Date], MAX(Data[Date]))
var nonBlankTab = CALCULATETABLE(FILTER(Data, NOT(ISBLANK(Data[Amount])) && Data[Date] <= curDate), REMOVEFILTERS(Data[Date]))
var rankedTab = TOPN(3, nonBlankTab, [Date])
return AVERAGEX(rankedTab, [Amount])
```

Comment: Just to add - with this approach, it's very easy to calculate an average over any number of non-blank sales, without introducing additional measures. You simply change one value (or base it on a slicer for instance) in the penultimate step, when you filter table with rank equal or lower than 3.

Comment: Looks very elegant and promising. I am crunching it. nonBlankTab and rankedTab are tables, aren't they?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin yes, they are tables.

Comment: The second attempt is great. If you could please mention in your answer your first attempt - I leave it here: `VAR rankedTab = FILTER ( ADDCOLUMNS ( nonBlankTab, "Rank", RANKX ( nonBlankTab, [Date] ) ), [Rank] <= 3 )` Because it allows for flexibility. If one wants just the N'th element, he can get it by turning <= to =.

Comment: How to crack another thing--I would like this AVERAGE by product. I tried `nonBlankTab = FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[product])` but it doesn't work. I'd be grateful for any clue.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I've updated my answer, as this is more universal, as all we want is to remove filter from `Date` really, so `ALL` is actuall killing other scenarios.

Comment: What is the reason for using the `REMOVEFILTERS(Data[Date])` in the CALCULATETABLE line? I would like to modify your solution (with the Date field of Sales table) to a data model with a Calendar table. Can you please have a look at the sample file I provided in my answer? I cannot see the reason for the REMOVEFILTERS.

Comment: The reason is that you need to remove Date context filter from the date column, because you want to displaying data for any date. If you do not remove filters, calculations will only be made for the date from the current row. I did take a look at your file and this bit: `'Calendar'[Date] <= _maxDate` does exactly the same, but introduces another evaluation, which is not necessary. Have a look at remarks section of `CALCULATE` docs:

*If the columns (or tables) are already in the filter context, the existing filters will be overwritten by the new filters to evaluate the CALCULATE expression*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax

I read your comment and the reason for introducing `'Calendar'[Date] <= _maxDate` is valid. In that case, `REMOVEFILTERS` is not necessary any more, as this line already overwrites any filters that may have been applied.

Comment: Should I impose the filter `__[Date] <= _maxDate` on Calendar table or on the Sales table? I want to be sure to see the AVERAGEX results (1) also on the dates (Calendar dates) that have no sales, and (2) only up to the last sales' day (not after it, as Calendar goes to 31 Dec).

Comment: Calendar. This is guaranteed (if it is in fact a designated date table) to have continuous days and that's what is going to be used to create visuals.

Comment: The problem is with `_maxDate = MAX( Sales[Date] )` It returns current date in context of visual that uses Calendar[date], so Calendar single dates influence its value. Consequently, I do not get results for the blank days. If I want to get the last day of product sales, I may use `_maxDate = CALCULATE( MAX( Sales[Date] ), REMOVEFILTERS( 'Calendar'[Date] ) )` Then I get results for blank days but I get the results until the end of the Calendar world, not until the last day of sales.

Comment: This produces correct results: `IF( _curDate <= _maxDate, _result )` but I wanted to avoid performance-killer IF.

Comment: You can always use `_maxDate = MAX(ALL(Sales[Date]))`. But it really depends on the context and usability design of the report.

Comment: Actuall, I think that will not work, as you will still have filters on Calendar[Date[, therefore, your proposal is correct, `_maxDate = CALCULATE( MAX( Sales[Date] ), REMOVEFILTERS( 'Calendar'[Date] ) )`. Apologies, but I'm typing on the go.

Answer (score 2):

Firs, create these below 3 measures-

```
n1 = 
VAR current_date = MIN(your_table_name[Date])
VAR first_max_date_with_no_blank = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[Date]),
    FILTER(ALL(your_table_name),  your_table_name[Date] <= current_date && your_table_name[Amount] <> BLANK())
)

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Date] = first_max_date_with_no_blank
    )
)
```

```
n2 = 
VAR current_date = MIN(your_table_name[Date])

VAR first_max_date_with_no_blank = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[Date]),
    FILTER(ALL(your_table_name),  your_table_name[Date] <= current_date && your_table_name[Amount] <> BLANK())
)

VAR second_max_date_with_no_blank = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[Date]),
    FILTER(ALL(your_table_name),  your_table_name[Date] < first_max_date_with_no_blank && your_table_name[Amount] <> BLANK())
)

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Date] = second_max_date_with_no_blank
    )
)
```

```
n3 = 
VAR current_date = MIN(your_table_name[Date])

VAR first_max_date_with_no_blank = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[Date]),
    FILTER(ALL(your_table_name),  your_table_name[Date] <= current_date && your_table_name[Amount] <> BLANK())
)

VAR second_max_date_with_no_blank = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[Date]),
    FILTER(ALL(your_table_name),  your_table_name[Date] < first_max_date_with_no_blank && your_table_name[Amount] <> BLANK())
)

VAR third_max_date_with_no_blank = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[Date]),
    FILTER(ALL(your_table_name),  your_table_name[Date] < second_max_date_with_no_blank && your_table_name[Amount] <> BLANK())
)

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Date] = third_max_date_with_no_blank
    )
)
```

Now create this final measure-

```
average = 

VAR sum_sales = [n1] + [n2] + [n3]
VAR devide_by = IF([n1] = BLANK(),0,1) + IF([n2] = BLANK(),0,1) + IF([n3] = BLANK(),0,1)

RETURN DIVIDE(sum_sales,devide_by)
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your effort put into this answer. It's readable educational material. Although I wish the solution was more concise.